# Question of identity mapping about $(f^{−1}\circ g^{−1})=(g\circ f)^{−1}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Let $g:X\to Y$ and $f:Y\to Z$ be bijection.
>
> Prove $(f^{−1}\circ g^{−1})=(g\circ f)^{−1}$
>
> for $f^{-1}:Z\to Y $, $g^{-1}:Y\to X$

1. $(f^{−1}\circ g^{−1})\circ (g\circ f)$
2. $f^{−1}\circ ((g^{−1}\circ g)\circ f)$          (assoicate law)
3. $f^{−1}\circ ((I_X)\circ f)$

Then I am stuck at here

Why $(g^{−1}\circ g)$ is $I_Y$ instead of $I_X$?

\begin{align}(g^{−1}\circ g)(x)&=g^{−1}(g(x))\\
&=g^{−1}(y)\\
&=I_X\end{align}

[image]

The image is from here:https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Composite_Bijection

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please add some more details around what it is you would like to know and what you have tried so far

Comment: i am stuck at step 3,any tips?I saw the proof wiki there should be Iy but i don't know why ,thanks

Comment: Your function compositions don't seem to be in the correct order.  $g\circ f$ should take something in the domain of $f$ (that is $Y$), but then $f$ maps that element to $Z$; from whence $g$ cannot subsequenly be applied.

Comment: @paw88789 I can finish it in the right order,but why the proof wiki can convert  $(g^{-1}∘g) $to $Iy $ direcly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g\circ f$ and $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$ don't make sense in the first place. If you fix the original problem statement so that the function compositions work, your proof will be well on the way to completion.

Which is to say, the picture in the post, and proof 2 in the given proofwiki link contains, at the time of writing this, a typo.

Comment: Thanks i edited the question,why the wiki can convert $(g^{-1}∘g)$ to $Iy$

Comment: @LeeSam Well, that is, as far as I can see, a typo.